# How do i refresh the position variable in case of item click of listvew?

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an android application in which the user select a particular food category (i.e itemlist.java). If the user selects Chicken then the respective items list will get displayed. Then when the user clicks back and clicks on another category (i.e. vegetarian delight) it is still displaying the same list as it did for Chicken.  The position variable gets changed but it doesn't upload catalog resources.
Please help me to solve this problem.

**Shoppincarthelper.java**

---

```
public class ShoppingCartHelper {
    public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";

    private static List<Product1> itemlist;
    private static List<Product> catalog;
    private static List<Product> cart;

    public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";

    public static List<Product> getCatalog(Resources res) {
        if(catalog == null) {
            catalog = new Vector<Product>();
            catalog.add(new Product("Chicken Kadai", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.new_kadai),"Kadai Chicken is a spicy chicken dish that is a little dry in nature with a rich aroma given by the Ginger and curry leaves",123, 0));
        }
        return catalog;
    }

    public static List<Product1> getCatalog1(Resources res) {
        if(itemlist == null) {
            itemlist = new Vector<Product1>();
            itemlist.add(new Product1("Chicken "));
            itemlist.add(new Product1("Vegetarian Delight"));
            itemlist.add(new Product1("Rice"));
            itemlist.add(new Product1("Drinks"));
        }
        return itemlist;
    }

    public static List<Product> getCatalog2(Resources res) {
        if(catalog == null) {
            catalog = new Vector<Product>();
            catalog.add(new Product("Chana Masala", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.chanamasala),
                " Chana masala or chole masala is a popular vegetable dish in Pakistani cuisine & Indian cuisine.The main ingredient is chickpeas.It is fairly dry and spicy with a sour citrus note. ",80));
        }
        return catalog;
    }

    public static List<Product> getCatalog3(Resources res) {
        if(catalog == null) {
            catalog = new Vector<Product>();
            catalog.add(new Product("Jeera Rice   ", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.jeerarice),
                "Jeera Rice (Cumin flavored rice), is a simple and tasty variation on plain boiled rice made with cumin seeds.  ",80));
            catalog.add(new Product("Filipino Fried Rice ", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.friedrice),
                "Philippine style fried rice is a simple dish of rice, meat/and or vegetables, a little oil, some spice and a garnish. ",95));
            catalog.add(new Product("VEG Biryani   ", res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.vegbiryani),
                "Vegetable Biryani, is a rich Indian Moghlai pullao layered with curry. Kabuli Chana Biryani, Hyderabadi Biryani and lots more ",60));
    }
```

**Itemlist.java**

---

```
public class ItemList extends Activity {
    private List<Product1> mProductList1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.itemlist);

        // Obtain a reference to the product catalog
        mProductList1 = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog1(getResources());

        // Create the list
        ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listViewCatalog.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter1(mProductList1, getLayoutInflater()));
        listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                Intent CatalogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),CatalogActivity.class);
                CatalogIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX,position);
                startActivity(CatalogIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CatalogActvity.java**

---

```
public class CatalogActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Product> mProductList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
    * @param CatalogIntent 
    * @param position */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.catalog);

        int ListIndex =getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);

        mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog(getResources());

        if(ListIndex==1)
        {
            mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog2(getResources());
        }
        if(ListIndex==2)
        {
            mProductList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCatalog3(getResources());
        }


        // Create the list
        ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
        listViewCatalog.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(mProductList, getLayoutInflater(), false));
        listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                Intent productDetailsIntent = new  Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
                startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
            }
         });

        Button viewShoppingCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonViewCart);
        viewShoppingCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent viewShoppingCartIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShoppingCartActivity.class);
                startActivity(viewShoppingCartIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent ListIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ItemList.class);
        startActivity(ListIntent);
    }
}
```

**ProductAdapter1.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {

 private List<Product1> mProductList1;
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public ProductAdapter1(List<Product1> list, LayoutInflater inflater) {
  mProductList1 = list;
  mInflater = inflater;  
 }

@Override
 public int getCount() {
  return mProductList1.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return mProductList1.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewItem item;

  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlistcon,null);
   item = new ViewItem();

   item.productTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   convertView.setTag(item);
  } else {
   item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
  }

  Product1 curProduct = mProductList1.get(position);
  item.productTitle.setText(curProduct.title);
  return convertView;
 }


 public class ViewItem 
 {
  TextView productTitle;
 }

}
```

Comment: It will be easier for ppl to help you if you post the entire classes, not cutting away the class definition, now we cant see if you subclass or inherit anything.

Comment: @erbsman Now I have posted the entire class defintion.

Comment: could you post a listing of ProductAdapter1.java to. I suspect that there might be something with your GetView().